# How to show on website differences between two texts (like diff or WinMerge but in JS)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have two texts and would like to show differences between them in way that WinMerge or diff from TortoiseSVN works. Do you know any JS library that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-diff-algorithm-2/.
Also, there are some userscripts at Wikipedia which try to improve MediaWikis native diff engine, the most familiar might be [Cacycles (WikiEd-) Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aCacycle/diff).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Diff is an algorithmic diff tool written in JavaScript.

http://prettydiff.com/